# How do I save Google API results into an array and add new results on it?

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to make a small web app as a side project that uses the Google API PHP client. After the application has been granted permission by the user, it requests the playlists of the user (mine=true parameter) and then it should save the names and IDs into an array. The problem I am having is the result of my limited PHP knowledge.

I am instantiating the Google and YouTube clients like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
```

Then I am making a request to the YouTube API like this :

```
$listResponse = $youtube->playlists->listPlaylists('snippet', $queryParams);
```

The `$listResponse` variable returns the correct results but it is an object which makes it very peculiar to me. This object contains several arrays and it makes it difficult for me to store this data. Then comes the issue of pagination. What is the best way for me to save the results of this request into an array (so I can store it in a database later) and add on top of these results the next page of results as required by pagination?

This is an example of the response from the API with two results (var_dump($listResponse)):

```
object(Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistListResponse)#89 (18) {
  ["collection_key":protected]=>
  string(5) "items"
  ["etag"]=>
  string(27) "zQG5YzR-JAU6eqwerdrAindolIs"
  ["eventId"]=>
  NULL
  ["itemsType":protected]=>
  string(31) "Google_Service_YouTube_Playlist"
  ["itemsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["kind"]=>
  string(28) "youtube#playlistListResponse"
  ["nextPageToken"]=>
  string(6) "CAQQAA"
  ["pageInfoType":protected]=>
  string(31) "Google_Service_YouTube_PageInfo"
  ["pageInfoDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["prevPageToken"]=>
  string(6) "CAIQAQ"
  ["tokenPaginationType":protected]=>
  string(38) "Google_Service_YouTube_TokenPagination"
  ["tokenPaginationDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["visitorId"]=>
  NULL
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["pageInfo"]=>
  object(Google_Service_YouTube_PageInfo)#93 (5) {
    ["resultsPerPage"]=>
    int(2)
    ["totalResults"]=>
    int(47)
    ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["modelData":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["processed":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["items"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Google_Service_YouTube_Playlist)#58 (17) {
      ["contentDetailsType":protected]=>
      string(45) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistContentDetails"
      ["contentDetailsDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["etag"]=>
      string(27) "IXu48tsFsPRHOKKrr-ITKuPp39A"
      ["id"]=>
      string(34) "PLYZiZDBjPdaZszrfW7goQLqAsde_XNMSs"
      ["kind"]=>
      string(16) "youtube#playlist"
      ["localizationsType":protected]=>
      string(43) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistLocalization"
      ["localizationsDataType":protected]=>
      string(3) "map"
      ["playerType":protected]=>
      string(37) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistPlayer"
      ["playerDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["snippetType":protected]=>
      string(38) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistSnippet"
      ["snippetDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["statusType":protected]=>
      string(37) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistStatus"
      ["statusDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["modelData":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["processed":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["snippet"]=>
      object(Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistSnippet)#65 (17) {
        ["collection_key":protected]=>
        string(4) "tags"
        ["channelId"]=>
        string(24) "UCBDfenjx1r7mZgHWksfpOuQ"
        ["channelTitle"]=>
        string(9) "the Legit"
        ["defaultLanguage"]=>
        NULL
        ["description"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["localizedType":protected]=>
        string(43) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistLocalization"
        ["localizedDataType":protected]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["publishedAt"]=>
        string(20) "2020-01-15T09:03:20Z"
        ["tags"]=>
        NULL
        ["thumbnailsType":protected]=>
        string(39) "Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails"
        ["thumbnailsDataType":protected]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["title"]=>
        string(5) "music"
        ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["modelData":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["processed":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["thumbnails"]=>
        object(Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails)#91 (16) {
          ["defaultType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["defaultDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["highType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["highDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["maxresType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["maxresDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["mediumType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["mediumDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["standardType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["standardDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["modelData":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["processed":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["default"]=>
          object(Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail)#94 (6) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(90)
            ["url"]=>
            string(46) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/o5AIp2Yc01M/default.jpg"
            ["width"]=>
            int(120)
            ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["modelData":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["processed":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          ["medium"]=>
          object(Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail)#95 (6) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(180)
            ["url"]=>
            string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/o5AIp2Yc01M/mqdefault.jpg"
            ["width"]=>
            int(320)
            ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["modelData":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["processed":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          ["high"]=>
          object(Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail)#96 (6) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(360)
            ["url"]=>
            string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/o5AIp2Yc01M/hqdefault.jpg"
            ["width"]=>
            int(480)
            ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["modelData":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["processed":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
        ["localized"]=>
        object(Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistLocalization)#97 (5) {
          ["description"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["title"]=>
          string(5) "music"
          ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["modelData":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["processed":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Google_Service_YouTube_Playlist)#98 (17) {
      ["contentDetailsType":protected]=>
      string(45) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistContentDetails"
      ["contentDetailsDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["etag"]=>
      string(27) "u8p3zQc4p0ouUduo7o52VI4-tRE"
      ["id"]=>
      string(34) "PLYZiZDBjPdaYHroslJaM21_60yEdP6FZE"
      ["kind"]=>
      string(16) "youtube#playlist"
      ["localizationsType":protected]=>
      string(43) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistLocalization"
      ["localizationsDataType":protected]=>
      string(3) "map"
      ["playerType":protected]=>
      string(37) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistPlayer"
      ["playerDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["snippetType":protected]=>
      string(38) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistSnippet"
      ["snippetDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["statusType":protected]=>
      string(37) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistStatus"
      ["statusDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["modelData":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["processed":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["snippet"]=>
      object(Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistSnippet)#99 (17) {
        ["collection_key":protected]=>
        string(4) "tags"
        ["channelId"]=>
        string(24) "UCBDfenjx1r7mZgHWksfpOuQ"
        ["channelTitle"]=>
        string(9) "the Legit"
        ["defaultLanguage"]=>
        NULL
        ["description"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["localizedType":protected]=>
        string(43) "Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistLocalization"
        ["localizedDataType":protected]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["publishedAt"]=>
        string(20) "2019-10-04T08:46:06Z"
        ["tags"]=>
        NULL
        ["thumbnailsType":protected]=>
        string(39) "Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails"
        ["thumbnailsDataType":protected]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["title"]=>
        string(10) "electronic"
        ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["modelData":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["processed":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["thumbnails"]=>
        object(Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails)#100 (18) {
          ["defaultType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["defaultDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["highType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["highDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["maxresType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["maxresDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["mediumType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["mediumDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["standardType":protected]=>
          string(32) "Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail"
          ["standardDataType":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["modelData":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["processed":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["default"]=>
          object(Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail)#101 (6) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(90)
            ["url"]=>
            string(46) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PTxkKPSZyMg/default.jpg"
            ["width"]=>
            int(120)
            ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["modelData":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["processed":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          ["medium"]=>
          object(Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail)#102 (6) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(180)
            ["url"]=>
            string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PTxkKPSZyMg/mqdefault.jpg"
            ["width"]=>
            int(320)
            ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["modelData":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["processed":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          ["high"]=>
          object(Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail)#103 (6) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(360)
            ["url"]=>
            string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PTxkKPSZyMg/hqdefault.jpg"
            ["width"]=>
            int(480)
            ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["modelData":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["processed":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          ["standard"]=>
          object(Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail)#104 (6) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(480)
            ["url"]=>
            string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PTxkKPSZyMg/sddefault.jpg"
            ["width"]=>
            int(640)
            ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["modelData":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["processed":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
          ["maxres"]=>
          object(Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail)#105 (6) {
            ["height"]=>
            int(720)
            ["url"]=>
            string(52) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PTxkKPSZyMg/maxresdefault.jpg"
            ["width"]=>
            int(1280)
            ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["modelData":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["processed":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
        ["localized"]=>
        object(Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistLocalization)#106 (5) {
          ["description"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["title"]=>
          string(10) "electronic"
          ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["modelData":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["processed":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant really help you covert the object to your own object as we dont know what your object looks like.

I can tell you that the object returned has an array called items this is a single row of type playlist.  I would start with looping though $listRespose->items

as for the pagination.  Something like this should work

```
$token = $results->getNextPageToken();
while($token != null) {    

   $params = array('pageToken' => $token);

   $listResponse = $youtube->playlists->listPlaylists('snippet', $params);

   $token = $results->getNextPageToken();

}
```

Comment: I just want to add the Items and their IDs to an array $results[] and add on the array the items of the next pages as well. Anyways thank you DalmTo you are always the first to respond with accurate solutions!

Comment: You can create a master list $allResponses and loop though $listResponse and add teach one to the list.  Or you can check if PHP has a add range method for arrays.  My php is quite rusty.   TBH if your storing these in your database you should store them by thirdpartyId that being the ID directly from Google if you dont want to use googles id orignally in your database.

Comment: hello thanks for the response! I want to use the original Google ID for archival reasons so I can know what video was using the specific ID!